# i3 is not fill when I'm using it with vga

Tags: debian, xrandr, i3

I'm using i3 with debian 9.4

I was using my external monitor with xfce4 perfectly, but since I can't use xfce4-display-manager with i3, I've tried that command:

```
 xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode 1920x1080
```

[But it simply put the screen at the corner of my external monitor.](http://image.ibb.co/fbimE7/5474_E1_DC_B69_A_4_B60_A043_FB578_F23_B1_A4.jpg)

How can I fix it? Have full screen output?

I've found that method:

```
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --mode 1366x768 --scale 1x1 --output VGA-1 --same-as LVDS-1 --mode 1920x1080 --scale 0.711x0.711
```

And It saved me from unnecessary margins, but resolution is low on external.

Comment: It would be relevant to add to the question if you are using an Orange PI.

Comment: Well I use asus x201e.